# Pandas groupby values in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, group-by

I am trying to return a `groupby` from a `pandas` `df`. I want the output values to be summed not `merged`. But the following `merges` the appropriate `lists`.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'Id' : [1,2,2,1],                 
    'Val' : ['A','B','B','A'],                  
    'Output' : [[1,2,3,4,5],[5,3,3,2,1],[6,7,8,9,1],[6,7,8,9,1]],                       
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df = df.groupby(['Id','Val']).agg({'Output':'sum'}, axis = 1)
```

Out:

```
                                Output
Id Val                                
1  A    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]
2  B    [5, 3, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]
```

Intended Output:

```
                                Output
Id Val                                
1  A    [7,9,11,13,6]
2  B    [11,10,11,11,2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or use a one-liner which converts to `np.array`:

```
df = df.groupby(['Id','Val']).apply(lambda x: x.Output.apply(np.array).sum())
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Id  Val
1   A        [7, 9, 11, 13, 6]
2   B      [11, 10, 11, 11, 2]
dtype: object
```

Comment: @Wen-Ben Thanks, will +1 for you too.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `list` to `numpy` `array` then

```
df.Output=df.Output.apply(np.array)

df.groupby(['Id','Val']).Output.apply(lambda x : np.sum(x))
Out[389]: 
Id  Val
1   A        [7, 9, 11, 13, 6]
2   B      [11, 10, 11, 11, 2]
Name: Output, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using using zip rather than using apply twice,

```
df.groupby(['Id','Val']).Output.apply(lambda x: [sum(i) for i in list(zip(*x))])

Id  Val
1   A        [7, 9, 11, 13, 6]
2   B      [11, 10, 11, 11, 2]
```